# running a java command within a batch file from visual studio project keeps erroring?

Tags: java, cmd, visual-studio-2013, console

Basically I have a project which I have started (first time using visual studio).

My program requires me to be able to run a batch file eg, apktool if framework-res.apk

When I run the batch there is a java command within the batch file but the cmd console outputs this

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now if I open cmd console and run the apk tool it works.

Here is the contents of my *apktool.bat*:

```
*@echo off

set PATH=%CD%;%PATH%;

java -jar "%~dp0\apktool.jar" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9*
```

and here is my code from visual studio:

```
*Private Sub Android50LPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Android50LPreviewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    **Shell("cmd /K c:\Zeustools\frameworks\apktool if framework-res_apiL.apk ")**
End Sub
End Class*
```

Can anyone help me understand where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you need to install Java.

Comment: java is installed and i have set a java_home variable in windows and like i said the batch file with the java command works fine if i open a cmd console but if i try to run the bacth file from within my Visual studio project i get the above error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output means 'java.exe' is not found in the current directory, nor in the path. Note that setting JAVA_HOME does not imply it is included in the path variable.

Also java.exe is located in %JAVA_HOME%\bin

You're probably best off modifying the scrip to :

```
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -jar "%~dp0\apktool.jar" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9*
```

This way you use the JAVA_HOME variable regardless of what the current directory or path variable is.

Comment: worked a treat and now i understand why it was not finding the java :P